# c# equivalent of nextElement() from Java

Tags: c#, java, .net

What is the equivalent of nextElement() from Java?

I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<String> e = (IEnumerable<String>)request
                                        .Params;

while (e.Count() > 1)
{
 // 
 //String name = e.nextElement();
String name = e. // what method?
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (string name in request.Params)
{
    // Do something for each name
}
```

If you really want to use the raw enumerable, then you have call its `GetEnumerator()` method:

```
using (IEnumerator<string> enumerator = request.Params.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string name = enumerator.Current;

        // Do something for each name
    }
}
```

However, the foreach syntax is *much* clearer. Use that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var enumerator = e.GetEnumerator();
while  (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    var name = enumerator.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` method. From an `IEnumerable`, you must first call the `GetEnumerator()` method to get an `IEnumerator`. Note that the `IEnumerator` interface is `IDisposable` which means, you need to use it inside a `using` clause.

As other guys suggest, you'll probably prefere using a `foreach` loop.